# AbsoluteLayout - do I have an alternative?

Tags: android, android-layout

In an app I'm developing, I need to layout 2 to 5 buttons as if on the edge of a circle. The app starts with 5 buttons, but buttons gradually disappear (based on user input) until there are 2 of them.

I thought I would use an `AbsoluteLayout` control, and set the position of each button in code (taking into account the screen size).  However, it says more or less *everywhere* that AbsoluteLayout should not be used. Since I'm targeting this app to Android 2.2 and up, I can't use the fancier layouts introduced with ICS.

I know I can use a RelativeLayout and play with the margins, but this seems less intuitive, and just as error prone, as using AbsoluteLayout.

Do I have any reasonable alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you dont have many alternatives. Except relative layout you mentioned, you could of course use FrameLayout and set left and bottom margin to position your buttons correctly.

Comment: This, again, seems very similar to the AbsoluteLayout, except being more sneaky.